# Edge Caching Size Limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to take advantage of the built-in Cloud Storage edge caching feature. When a valid `Cache-Control` header is set, the files can be stored at edge locations. This is without having to set up Cloud Load Balancer & CDN. This built-in behavior is touched on in this [Cloud Next '18 video](https://youtu.be/kNUlvj3vDWk?t=642).

What I am seeing though is a hard limit of 10 MB. When I store a file over 10 MB and then download it, it's missing the `Age` response header. A 9 MB file will have it. The 10 MB limit is mentioned in the CDN docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#maximum-size), though. What doesn't make sense to me is why files over 10 MB don't get cached to the edge. After all, the Cloud Storage server meets all the requirements, [it even says](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#byte-range-requests): *Cloud Storage supports byte range requests for most objects.*

Does anyone know more about the default caching limits? I can't seem to find any limits documented for Cloud Storage.

Comment: Official documentation states: If you have Cloud Storage objects larger than 10 MB, make sure that they do not have Content-Encoding: gzip metadata. Are you getting some error message ? how you are doing the requests?

Comment: My files do not have a Content-Encoding set. No error message, just a difference in download times and the missing Age header that would be set if the file was served from edge cache.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the information of the cache limit managed by the objects in Cloud Storage is documented in the Cloud DN [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#maximum-size) and what you describe is an expected behavior.

> Origin server does not support byte range requests: 10 MB (10,485,760
> bytes)

Performing tests on my side with files of an exact size of 10,485,760 bytes include the Age field.

[image]

However files above that limit such as 10,485,770 no longer include it.

[image]

I recommend you create a feature request [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) in order to improve the Google Cloud Storage documentation.

In this way you will have direct communication with the team responsible for the documentation and your request may be supported by other members of the community.

Comment: I saw the max CDN size, but Cloud Storage buckets meet all the requirements for larger sizes. I did file feedback via "Send Feedback". Hopefully they will address it.